# Can't connect through ssh from remote computer but can locally

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have an archlinux computer running openssh that I can connect to locally with no issues. However when I try and connect from another network I get errors. SSH is listening to port 22 but I set up my router to portforward port 25 to 22 because I have more than one machine set up to ssh into on port 22.

Using putty `I get Incoming packet was garbled on decryption` I have tried moving blowfish to the top and in Connection>SSH>Cipher and tried moving 3DES to the top. And am using putty version .64

Using MobaXterm I get

`Bad packet length 1349676916.
 Disconnecting: Packet corrupt`

and when I manually run

```
ssh username@ip -vp 25

OpenSSH_6.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to MY-IP [MY-IP] port 25.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Bad packet length 1349676916.
Disconnecting: Packet corrupt
```

if I use -1 when running ssh I get

```
Protocol major versions differ: 1 vs. 2
```

As far as I understand it the port is properly forwarded. 
Also I connected with telnet and got

```
Trying MY-IP...
Connected to MY-IP.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
```

I can connect to other machines on the network and then use those to ssh into this one. The other two machines are raspberry pi's and I feel trying to use them as the access point might cause delays so I would rather get this fixed if possible.

Comment: Does it work when you change the port to something outside well known ports? (In case your ISp tries to be smart with SMTP).

Comment: Seems to be working with port 35. I didn't realize port 25 was generally used for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working with port 35. I didn't realize port 25 was generally used for something else. Switching to another port and setting it up as a static IP seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: For future reference, here is a list of [well known port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). In this case 25 is usually used for mail and most ISP block or somehow filter that by default.